# Change working directory swi-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, working-directory

Using the predicate `working_directory(CWD, 'new/WD/folder')` change your current working directory for the whole time of the current session. What I need is to change it permanentely. I tried using the predicate cd/1 , I tried editing the swipl.ini file inserting the working_directory predicate in it but nothing seems to work. I don't know if I am placing the.ini file in the wrong folder or if the statements in it are not correct. Is it even possible to achieve such result? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add to the SWI-Prolog initialization file (`swipl.ini` on Windows; `.swiplrc` on POSIX systems) the **directive**:

```
:- working_directory(_, 'new/WD/folder').
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not work even so. Where do I place the file? Mine is in the original working directory.

Comment: In your home directory.

Comment: This is not working to me too. It is always redirects to the default one.